# How to pass multiple RTP options to ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

Building my own RTSP server for FFMPEG, so I'm executing ffmpeg as a child process.

The problem I currently have is that I'm adding multicast support, and an RTSP client may add `ttl` to the RTSP Transport line. No problem so far, as ffmpeg supports that. But exactly how do I pass it? The documented URL format is

```
 rtp://hostname[:port][?option=val...]
```

That's not the sort of definition you should write if you want to pass a Comp.Sci class. The ellipsis suggests you can pass more than one parameter, but not *how*. And I need not just `ttl=` but also `localrtpport=`.

I suppose I could follow HTTP conventions and assume that they intended `[?option=val[&option=val]*]` but I can't find an authoritative source for that.

Asked [elsewhere](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1418) but unanswered there too.

Comment: I'd at least try the ?option=val&option2=val2  It's easy to try and if it works go answer this question and let us all know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cheated and looked at the source.

[`rtp_open`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/rtpproto_8c_source.html) calls [`av_find_info_tag`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/parseutils_8c.html#ad97f06e907c14c253c2bf3e775f51ccb)  which is documented to parse `?tag1=val1&tag2=val2...`.

And to answer the obvious follow-up questions, I also checked the source for `av_find_info_tag`. There is no limit on the number of arguments that can be passed, they have to be separated by `&`, and (implementation detail) only the first occurrence of a parameter is used. Unsupported parameters are silently ignored.